# Get Dynamic Type by key object

Tags: typescript

I need pass enum value to the template key and  the context key only show me properties referenced in TemplatesMail keys
But TS show all properties like CancellationPolicyContext & AnotherMailContext

```
enum TemplateEnum {
  CANCELLATION_POLICY = 'cancellation-policy',
  ANOTHER_MAIL = 'another-mail'
}

type CancellationPolicyContext = {
  name: string
  cancellationDate: Date
}

type AnotherMailContext = {
  value: number
}

type TemplatesMail = {
  [TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY]: CancellationPolicyContext
  [TemplateEnum.ANOTHER_MAIL]: AnotherMailContext
}

type SendMailParams = {
  template: TemplateEnum
  context: TemplatesMail[TemplateEnum]
} 

const params: SendMailParams = {
  template: TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY,
  context: {
    // need show only properties from CancellationPolicyContext
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5eb9N) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer (after I do a dupe search).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeap! How this works?

Comment: I will write up an answer explaining it when I get a chance; might not be for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the type

```
type SendMailParams = {
  template: TemplateEnum
  context: TemplatesMail[TemplateEnum]
}
```

is that it allows each property to correspond to any value from the `TemplateEnum` enum [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  There is no constraint that forces the `template` and `context` properties to each correspond tot he same enum value.  So a value of the type `{template: TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY, context: AnotherMailContext}` is allowed.

What you really want to do is say that *for each* member in the `TemplateEnum` union, you want a corresponding `SendMailParams` type for just that member.  So you want to *distribute* the union in `TemplateEnum` over the original `SendMailParams` type.

For that we can use a *distributive object* type (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)).  It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which you immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`.  If `K` is a union of keylike types (such as `TemplateEnum`) of the form `K1 | K2 | K3 | ...` then the distributive object type above evaluates to `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3> | ...`.

So here it is for `SendMailParams`:

```
type SendMailParams = { [K in TemplateEnum]: {
  template: K,
  context: TemplatesMail[K]
} }[TemplateEnum];
```

IntelliSense shows you that this type is

```
/* type SendMailParams = {
    template: TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY;
    context: CancellationPolicyContext;
} | {
    template: TemplateEnum.ANOTHER_MAIL;
    context: AnotherMailContext;
} */
```

which is the union you want.  In fact it is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) so the compiler will enforce that the `template` property determines the shape of the rest of the object.  Now if you write `template: TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY`, the type checker will immediately treat the `context` property as being of type `CancellationPolicyContext` and your IntelliSense will only show you appropriate properties:

```
const params: SendMailParams = {
  template: TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY,
  context: {
    cancellationDate: new Date(),
    name: "abc"
  }
} // okay

const badParams: SendMailParams = {
  template: TemplateEnum.CANCELLATION_POLICY,
  context: {
    value: 1 // error!
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsEAcA2BDALsAouaBvAsAFBRQDCAggHKmYAyt5MAkgPKUD6ACi7U6QJpQAvFADkAYxQhxwJKjQBLAPYgAtAiVIF4gJ6iANERJUWMABKYASuwCy5JrWFipStAAtgAJ1UQUCpKJEAL5ERGg6CMBkUjJy6MognJraOqQqGAAeaE4ExFAgKBDAAFxQAM5ongogAOZGUJLSsvIJACLoJVDtGMGhhOGRUOQgrh6eNn5IaSCZ2SK5JABuKEhgnTgARl69hGERUXCI8sBlE-459QDah8gd2JAAdBTUdAzMbFw8fPwAuqWkMWa8RUSS0ummsyuN2O9wgDxM5istnstD+QxG7i8Zym6WAWR2e0GAGVQAATbGcFCeQplHJQS4AaSg1Vg8FuGFhaIWUAwRw6pQZhjy4lxWVK0I6p0mjJ+wSgQWubJhOB+AG4+gB6ABUPP2UBJIHJk0p1IgtPm9RIvPZnQlHJwTyoNHojFYHG4vAE6ryJBFMzxaH+gLiihByXBorQ3qCUAAPlBuValfzWXz7Y8ERZrHYHN6SL7I6VhqMsZMIQHo1AtRq+n6KlAEFSaaUDUb-CaaRc8tbjuLk+m4c9nW83Z9PfwhQX-WKE5aGsGWipuutgAB3LodAAUAEpJ-mCkVSgAiFAbcRH+ohQgxjUaqBKADWKB0fSIdeyGxQpI7ZpbZIpTZml2SZpra-ZYA6Q6vK6Hwet8e5+rMpSJlAyyrJ0ACMUC3lAXieEongAISXsEQA)